# How to not run php script upon failed javascript validation?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a simple html signup form with onsubmit = "return validateForm()" where validateForm() is javascript to ensure input is in the correct form and e-mail and password fields match their confirm fields.

The forms action is set to add.php. add.php adds the input into a mysql database. Both the javascript and php work fine, however even when javascript alerts an error such as "password too short." the php script is run anyways and a new entry made in the database.

I would like the php script to only run upon successful javascript validation, and the user to remain on the same page if any validation fails, how is this done?

I can add code if needed but I think the answer here would be generic.

EDIT:

for example here is the code for validating name fields:

```
function checkName()
{
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var lName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    if (fName.value.length >= 2 && fName.value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/) && lName.value.length >= 2 && lName.value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
        {
            return true;
        }
    else
        {
            return false;
        }
}

function validateForm(){
if (checkName() == false)
        {
            alert("First and Last Name must be at least 2 characters long and contain  only alphabetic characters");
        document.getElementById("fName").focus();
        document.getElementById("fName").select();
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: have `validateForm()` return false on error. Also, you should validate that stuff in php too before doing an insert because it is crazy easy to bypass javascript validating.

Comment: This is just a school assignment, security is of no concern. Also my validateForm() does return false upon fail. I will edit the original post with an example function.

Comment: if you call your function using onclick="return validateForm()" it should stop the form from submitting as jKuhn pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Is it `firstName` or `fName`? If the `fName` ID doesn't exist, the function will hit an error and exit without returning anything, causing the alert to show, but the form to still submit.

Comment: the id is firstName I just called the variable fName. That shouldn't matter should it? I see that my focus() and select() are using the wrong id but I fixed those to no success.

Comment: The argument of `getElementById` must exactly match the ID of the element, not a variable.

Comment: yes, and the Id for the elements are firstName and lastName. I did however, just change every instance including var names to firstName and lastName and it seemed to work. I don't understand why though I could have called the var poopmonkey if I wanted right?

Comment: What happens if you run those two lines in the browser console? Something is causing an error between the alert and the return.